# Need this Query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a following set of data.

http://i57.tinypic.com/sn2y6a.jpg

And i'm trying hard to sort this data as below.

So, Below is the output data.

http://i58.tinypic.com/xptth2.jpg

1)There is a new column EndDate. It is calculated as,
if there is a one/duplicate record for StartDate, take it as StartDate and then the next nearest date should be the EndDate. and for next row, this EndDate should be as a StartDate and the next nearest for this startdate should be EndDate and it should continue for the ID.

2)For ID 1, i have 4 records. For this ID, If there is one record for FirstName, it should be picked and Null should be eliminated. And same for LastName and even MiddleName.

Comment: One of the links is wrong?

Comment: Sorry JamesZ. Its correct now...Appreciate your help

Comment: Gee this question sure look familiar...http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1658378-23-1.aspx

Comment: low quality of the question, @SQLquery what have u tried so far?

Comment: From several tables, i extracted this data as a prefinal stage. Not the only this strucked is with transformation of enddate from startdate.

Comment: @Sean,
Yes its the same question i asked on SSC. Thanks for  checking....

Comment: I provided an answer to your same question on the other site where you had provided enough information to let us answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data is in such a format that only way I can figure out to do this is use a cursor and gather the dates into a table variable, and the other field just to normal variables. When start date of the row is earlier than previous row, add the gathered data into another result table variable and clear the previously used variables and do the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    ID, StartDate,
    (select min(StartDate) from T as t2 where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.StartDate > t1.StartDate) as EndDate,
    (select max(FirstName) from T as t2 where t2.ID = t1.ID) as FirstName,
    (select max(LastName) from T as t2 where t2.ID = t1.ID) as LastName,
    (select max(MiddleName) from T as t2 where t2.ID = t1.ID) as MiddleNameName
from T as t1
group by ID, StartDate
```

Substitute T for your table's name. You might prefer to write it with a `CROSS APPLY` instead. And I'm making some assumptions in using `MAX()`.

Comment: That was a different "Shawn."